# Why am I getting a hidden[0] size... error when I try generating the output to my pytorch LSTM model?

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, lstm

The model is constantly throwing out a:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Projects\Crptic\CrpticMain\TrainedModel.py", line 146, in <module>
    print(generate_code(model, input_text.lower()))
  File "d:\Projects\Crptic\CrpticMain\TrainedModel.py", line 115, in generate_code
    output, hidden = model(input_tensor, hidden)
  File "C:\Users\aadi_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\Projects\Crptic\CrpticMain\TrainedModel.py", line 38, in forward
    output, hidden = self.lstm(input, hidden)
  File "C:\Users\aadi_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aadi_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\rnn.py", line 810, in forward
    self.check_forward_args(input, hx, batch_sizes)
  File "C:\Users\aadi_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\rnn.py", line 731, in check_forward_args
    self.check_hidden_size(hidden[0], self.get_expected_hidden_size(input, batch_sizes),
  File "C:\Users\aadi_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\rnn.py", line 239, in check_hidden_size
    raise RuntimeError(msg.format(expected_hidden_size, list(hx.size())))
RuntimeError: Expected hidden[0] size (1, 16, 256), got [1, 1, 256]
```

I have tried looking around and changing the generation function and model object, but nothing has been working.
I am training on CPU with a relatively small dataset.
I am also using pytorch.
Here is the code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import pandas as pd
import random
import os

save_dir = 'Model'
if not os.path.exists(save_dir):
    os.makedirs(save_dir)
save_path = os.path.join(save_dir, 'lstm_model.pt')

model_path = 'Model/lstm_model.pt'


random.seed(0)
data = pd.read_csv('dataset.tsv', delimiter='\t')

# model
class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.encoder = nn.Embedding(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.decoder = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, inp, hidden):
        # Reshape the input tensor to the expected shape
        inpp = inp.view(1, -1)
        
        # Pass the input tensor through the model
        inpp = self.encoder(inpp)
        output, hidden = self.lstm(inpp, hidden)
        output = self.decoder(output.view(len(inpp), -1))
        
        return output, hidden

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        return (torch.zeros(1, batch_size, self.hidden_size),
                torch.zeros(1, batch_size, self.hidden_size))



# training function
def train(model, optimizer, criterion, input_tensor, target_tensor):
    hidden = model.init_hidden(1)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    input_length = input_tensor.size(0)
    target_length = target_tensor.size(0)
    loss = 0
    for i in range(input_length):
        output, hidden = model(input_tensor[i], hidden)
    for i in range(target_length):
        output, hidden = model(target_tensor[i], hidden)
        loss += criterion(output, target_tensor[i].unsqueeze(dim=0))
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    return loss.item() / target_length

# Define the random input function
def random_input():
    row = data.sample(1)
    input_text = row.iloc[0]['input']
    target_text = row.iloc[0]['output']
    return input_text, target_text

# hyperparameters
input_size = 256
hidden_size = 256
output_size = 256
learning_rate = 0.01
n_epochs = 100

# Initialize
model = LSTMModel(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

try:
    print("Found model instance!")
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path))
    model.eval()
except:
    # Train
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        input_text, target_text = random_input()
        input_tensor = torch.tensor([ord(c) for c in input_text])
        target_tensor = torch.tensor([ord(c) for c in target_text])
        loss = train(model, optimizer, criterion, input_tensor, target_tensor)
        print(f'Epoch {epoch} Loss: {loss}')
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), save_path)
    
# Generation
def generate_code(model, input_text):
    with torch.no_grad():
        
        vocab = {char: i for i, char in enumerate(set(input_text))}
        vocab['<start>'] = 0
        input_tensor = torch.tensor([vocab[char] for char in list(input_text.lower())], dtype=torch.long)

    
        input_tensor = input_tensor.unsqueeze(0)

        start_token = torch.tensor([vocab['<start>']]).repeat(input_tensor.size(0), 1)
        input_tensor = torch.cat([start_token, input_tensor], dim=1)

        hidden = model.init_hidden(1)
        output, hidden = model(input_tensor, hidden)

        
        _, topi = output[-1].topk(1)
        code = chr(topi.item())

        
        while code not in ['\n', ':']:
            input_tensor = torch.tensor([vocab[char] for char in code], dtype=torch.long)
            output, hidden = model(input_tensor.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0), hidden)
            _, topi = output[-1].topk(1)
            code += chr(topi.item())

        
        if code[-1] == '\n' or code[-1] == ':':
            return code
        else:
            return generate_code(model, code)

print("Save model to Models folder")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    model = LSTMModel(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path))

    input_text = "make a print statement"
    print('here is what is being fed: ' + input_text.lower())
    print(generate_code(model, input_text.lower()))
```

Stackoverflow had some of the same questions but no answers.

I tried looking on google and youtube.  Those didn't work, so I tried my code and error into AI tools like Bard and ChatGPT and even they couldn't figure it out. What I am expecting it to output is, "print('hello world')" when I give it the string "make a print statement." Everything is in the vocab for that, but it just doesn't work. It resulted in the error I showed.

Comment: In deep learning models, it's crucial that the size of the output of a layer matches the size of the input of a layer. It seems like you've got a batch of 16 somewhere trying to match with a batch of 1. (side note: in my experience, Bard is not nearly at the level of ChatGPT yet, and using LLMs for programming is better if you're already familiar with the frameworks that it's using, you can ask it more focused questions, I highly recommend the book Deep Learning with Pytorch)

Comment: @BrockBrown I am trying to find the batch size that is 16 in it. Trust me I used the AI as last resort because I have no clue where it is saying batch size is 16. I am trying to work this out with what you gave me. Thanks!

Comment: This is a little bit of an anti-answer, but it might be worth it to take an existing example and modify it to your purpose. I took a pretty good look at it and I'm really unsure as to where this happens. Also this is nitpicky, but generally batch size in Pytorch is in the first dimension, i.e.: 8 batches of a tensor of 24 floats should be the shape 8 x 24. In Pytorch, for certain functions batch is assumed (like in NNs), and so if you don't do that, some Pytorch functions might not work like you expect them to. https://machinelearningmastery.com/text-generation-with-lstm-in-pytorch/

Comment: @BrockBrown Thanks for the source. I decided to also find some ready made examples and just modified it, and my text generation AI is now working. Thanks! I used keras instead of pytorch this time.